# My program in python to count the number of different words only returns the value six. Any ideas why?

Tags: python, file-io

Here is my code. I am using Python:

```
import re
file = open('TEST.txt')
text = file.read()
file.close()
words = list(text.split())
myset= set(words)
num = len(myset)
print (num)
```

When I run it, it prints 6 no matter how long the text file is. Why would this be and how would I fix it?

Comment: Can you please provide the content of such a text file?

Comment: Remember to put the `TEST.txt` file in the same directory of the `.py` file

Comment: Make sure you're reading the right file.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `set()`; your file consists of only six *unique* words. Repeating the same 6 words over and over again won't make the count go up.

Either don't use a set (which can only hold unique values), or use other words in your file:

```
>>> words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> len(words)
6
>>> len(set(words))
3
>>> set(words)
set(['baz', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

You are also using a *relative* filename; `TEST.txt` will be opened in the current directory; change your current directory (in your terminal, using `os.chdir()`, etc.) and a different file will be opened if there is *another* `TEST.txt` file there.

Use `print(words)` to see if you are still opening the right text file, check for the current directory with `import os; print(os.getcwd())`, or better still, use an absolute file path (with all the directories specified explicitly).

Comment: I think that's what he's trying to do. Counting the number of different words. He seems to understand what sets are for.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, since this is what he is trying to do.

Comment: @aIKid: That's just as much speculation, isn't it?

Comment: @Christian: We are all guessing here; so far I can see two options: wrong file, or not realizing that the set is working...

Comment: Yeah.. We need to remember the rules that we talked about yesterday..

Comment: @MartijnPieters with the edit, now IMO this is a complete answer `+1`

Comment: Another possible guess would be that in his actual code he accidentally uses the filename instead of the text for the set, as `len(set("TEST.txt"))` is coincidentally `6`...